# lodash includes not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I am using loadash 4.11.1 version via nodejs.

```
console.log(req.groupMemberOf, groupId, [groupId]); 
// ["572cc00b703ddd760bd5c009"] '572cc00b703ddd760bd5c009' [ '572cc00b703ddd760bd5c009' ]


console.log(_.includes([groupId], groupId)); 
// true

console.log(_.includes(req.groupMemberOf, groupId)); 
// false

req.groupMemberOf.indexOf(groupId)
// 0
```

Why is `console.log(_.includes(req.groupMemberOf, groupId))` returning `false`? It works when I use indexOf.

Comment: is `groupId` a string? you're casting it to one in your `console.log` at the beginning, but is it actually a string?

Comment: Running `_.includes(['572cc00b703ddd760bd5c009'], '572cc00b703ddd760bd5c009');` returns `true`

Comment: @winhowes It a string. The result is same without casting also. Removed it now

Comment: @winhowes for me too running
console.log(_.includes([groupId], groupId)) returns true.

Comment: does `req.groupMemberOf[0] === groupId` then? if so I'm stumped. My guess then is that `req.groupMemberOf` is not the same as `[groupId]`

Comment: what is type of `req.groupMemberOf`? Make sure it is array. Look at this `["572cc00b703ddd760bd5c009"] '572cc00b703ddd760bd5c009' [ '572cc00b703ddd760bd5c009' ]`, the log result for `req.groupMemberOf` and `[groupId]` are different somehow (single quote vs double quote).

Comment: Can't reproduce with the provided data ~ https://jsfiddle.net/fwqexa8n/1/

Comment: @BryanChen The type is object. I think I need to convert it to array.

Comment: @Phil in your fiddle, `req.groupMemberOf` should be an array.

Comment: @ArunGhosh `includes` is a collection function so it should work on objects too. You can still try to convert to an array to narrow down the cause of that issue.

Comment: Not sure if it was just that version of lodash. Can't reproduce on latest version. https://jsfiddle.net/fwqexa8n/2/

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen oops, fixed (still not reproducible) ~ https://jsfiddle.net/fwqexa8n/3/

Comment: Also check `req.groupMemberOf.length`. `_.includes({1:'a', length: 0}, 'a')` is false and `_.includes({1:'a'}, 'a')` is true